# OpenCV Jigsaw Puzzle get "clean" contours

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, image-segmentation

I have a photo of a finished jigsaw puzzle and I want to get "clean" contours in order to match single puzzle pieces.
[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwJbE.jpg)

For the current result I'm using the following steps:
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkcs.png)

```
img = cv2.imread("img.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
blank = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 4), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > 600:
        cv2.drawContours(blank, contours, i, (255,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.imshow("blur", blur)
cv2.imshow("threshold", threshold)
cv2.imshow("contours", blank)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I need to use an adaptive threshold because the full source image has bad light conditions:
[Full source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7eft.jpg)
To clean up most of the noise I'm filtering contours with small areas.

What step am I missing in order to get clean contours without noise?

Comment: What language are you programming in?  What are the results you are experiencing now?

Comment: @zkilnbqi it's python. Since I don't have 10 rep yett, I'm not able to embed images. So I linked the "current result" here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFkcs.png

Comment: dst = cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21) - denoising works better then median blur.